# MongoDB Panache Updating nested objects within Document

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a model which looks like this:

```js
{
  "projectName": "MyFirstProject",
  "projectId": "1234",
  "testCaseList": [
    {
      "testCaseName": "TestCase1",
      "steps": [
        {
          "Action": "Click on this",
          "Result": "pass"
        },
        {
          "Action": "Click on that",
          "Result": "pass"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "testCaseName": "TestCase2",
      "steps": [
        {
          "Action": "Click on him",
          "Result": "pass"
        },
        {
          "Action": "Click on her",
          "Result": "pass"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, as this is a nested object, I am having difficulties updating it using the method:

```java
default PanacheUpdate update(String update, Object... params)
```

I am using Repository Pattern and below is my code snippet:

```java
List<TestCase> newTestCaseList = ...;
update("testCaseList", newTestCaseList).where("projectId=?1",projectId);
```

which actually throws the following error:

```java
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found ','.
at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:149)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:82)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.parse(BsonDocument.java:63)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime.MongoOperations.executeUpdate(MongoOperations.java:634)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime.MongoOperations.update(MongoOperations.java:629)
```

**My Current Approach**

What currently works for me is to use `default void update(Entity entity)` instead when updating nested objects.
This however presents a few considerations:

1. Extra code is required to fetch the entire document, parse through, and update the required fields
2. Since `update(Entity entity)` works on a document level, it will also update unchanged parts of the document, which isn't ideal.

Comment: `update(Entity)` is the method designed to update an entity. And yes you need to load the entity first as it's a full update.
`update(String)` is designed for multi-document update, of course you should be able to use it for a single document.
Can you activate query debugging https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#query-debugging and update your question with the generated query ?
You can also access the collection via `TestCase.mongoCollection()` and perform native query on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the encountered error states nothing but a limitation of `Panache` for *mongoDB* for the moment through the standard offered *PanacheQL*.

The issue should be worked-around using native *mongoDB* Java API that can be accessed through the `PanacheMongoEntityBase#mongoCollection`:

```java
mongoCollection().updateOne(
        eq("projectId", projectId),
        new Document("$set", new Document("testCaseList", newTestCaseList))
);
```